# How to use apache drill with java and maven?

Tags: java, maven, apache-drill

I am trying out the drill sample in my project using this example.

https://github.com/vicenteg/DrillJDBCExample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mapr/drill/DrillJDBCExample.java

I've included the dependency in my maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The error I am getting is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J

I tried to resolve it by adding Google Guava:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when I included the dependency in my pomfile, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed()` method was removed in Guava 16. You must be using Guava 16+.

Drill is using **Guava 14.0.1**. *That's the reason of your issue.* So, with Drill 1.4, use Guava 14.0.1.

There is an issue for upgrading Guava Jar to **18.0** in Drill Jira. Check [details](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3581). It's is fixed for upcoming Drill version 1.6.